# AWS Elastic Beanstalk save file to S3 or application directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application deployed on EB that need to download a file from a remote server then serve to visitors

As I understand, Its recommended to save files to S3 instead then grant users access to these files. However, I believe there is no option for S3 to initiate the download of a file on a remote server therefore the process would be :

> EB application get the files => EB application upload the files to S3.

That would double the wait time for users.

Should I save files directly to the application directory instead as I will only use 200-300MB max then clean it daily.

Is there any risk or better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would it double the time? The upload to S3 would be extremely quick. You could even stream the file to S3 as it is being downloaded.

Saving the files to the server will prevent you from scaling your application beyond a single server.